# IOS 6 ARC Unrecognized Selector Sent to Instance

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, xcode4.5

I hope someone can help with this.

I have a UITableViewController and want to pass a value to a UIViewController called NewsArticleViewController when the tablecell is selected. I've created a segue from the tablecell to the view controller.

When I call my prepareForSegue method below:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowNewsArticle"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self._tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSDictionary *article = [_articles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *articleID = [article valueForKey:@"id"];
        NSLog(@"Trying %@", articleID);

        NewsArticleViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        detailViewController.articleID = articleID;
    }
}
```

The NSLog shows the NSString value correctly before the error occurs on the last line.

I get the error:

```
2012-12-11 23:08:41.915 My School[4689:c07] -[UIViewController setArticleID:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8088140
2012-12-11 23:08:41.916 My School[4689:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController setArticleID:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8088140'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1800012 0x11c5e7e 0x188b4bd 0x17efbbc 0x17ef94e 0x3ca1 0x554ac7 0x554b54 0x1bc899 0x1bcb3d 0xbc3e83 0x17bf376 0x17bee06 0x17a6a82 0x17a5f44 0x17a5e1b 0x1cc87e3 0x1cc8668 0x10d65c 0x1f4d 0x1e75 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

On the destination view controller, NewsArticleViewController, I have declared this in the header:

```
@property(strong,nonatomic) id articleID;
```

And I have synthesized the property in the method. I'm using ARC, I don't know if this is the specific cause but I can't proceed until I sort this out. Thanks.

Comment: are you sure that destinationViewController is returning a NewsArticleViewController?

Comment: At the debugger command prompt (where it says lldb or gdb) type in the following "po [0x8088140 class]  and hit enter. Except, replace the 0x8088140 with whatever pointer you have at the end of the error string 'unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8088140'. let me know what class is there. My guess is that destination view controller is not actually a NewsArticleViewController instance

Comment: It's probably a UINavigationController and not a NewsArticleViewController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your error message, `UIViewController` is reporting the "unrecognized selector" error. I suspect your storyboard has not specified your custom `NewsArticleViewController` for this scene. Thus, it's using the default `UIViewController` which obviously doesn't understand the `setArticleID`.

Check the "Custom Class" setting for the view controller in Interface Builder:

[image]

If the custom class has not specified, it will look like the above screen snapshot. Just fill in the class name.

Comment: Face Palm. I could've sworn I'd checked that, obviously not. Thank you ever so much for your help. You've made a tired guy happy :)